# Multiply values from different tables, SQL oracle database

Tags: sql

I have two three tables:

```
clients(client_id, f_name, l_name)
cars(car_id,model,price,..) 
reservation(res_id, client_id_fk,by_date, up_to_date, car_id_fk)
```

Now I need to display the bill for reserved car (`F_name | L_name | price* number of days`)

I tried to make this but i get error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

This is how i tried:

```
select f_name, 
       l_name, 
       sum(cars.price*(date(reservation.up_to_date)-date(reservation.by_date))) 
from clients 
join reservation
where reservation.client_id_fk=clients.client_id
```

How would you do this in Oracle SQl database?

Comment: first, change the `where` to `on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the three tables together. Then you can simply calculate the date difference in days by subtracting the dates. We add one to the days, since when both dates are equal you want to charge 1 day, not 0.

```
select
    clients.f_name || ' ' || clients.l_name || ' ' ||
    to_char(cars.price * (reservation.up_to_date - reservation.by_date + 1), '$99,990.99')
from
    clients
    inner join reservation
        on clients.client_id = reservation.client_id_fk
    inner join cars
        on reservation.car_id_fk = cars.car_id
```

See: [Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements4a.htm#34773) for number formats.

You can also use aliases for the table names in order to be more concise:

```
select
    c.f_name || ' ' || c.l_name || ' ' ||
    to_char(cars.price * (r.up_to_date - r.by_date + 1), '$99,990.99')
from
    clients c
    inner join reservation r
        on c.client_id = r.client_id_fk
    inner join cars
        on r.car_id_fk = cars.car_id
```